# How do I make the label red every 6 units on a horizontal axis in an Excel chart?

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry, I can't post an image, so here's a link to a picture of my graph:

[image]

I want to make 206T3, 205T1, 203T3, and 202T1 red, specifically, a red with RGB values (192, 80, 77). Like, I want the text of these four indices to be the color red on the graph. How do I do that?

Thank you so much!

EDIT: I am so sorry for not posting my code!

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim HelpMePlease_Chart As Chart

    Set HelpMePlease_Chart = Charts.Add

    With HelpMePlease_Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1:$C$24")
        .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
        .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.0"
        .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Orientation = xlUpward
        .Axes(xlCategory).AxisBetweenCategories = False
        .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleNone)
        .SetElement (msoElementLegendNone)
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesMajor)
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesMinorMajor)
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesMinorMajor)
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = 8
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).MarkerSize = 5
        .FullSeriesCollection(2).MarkerStyle = 1
        .FullSeriesCollection(2).MarkerSize = 5
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1"
    End With

End Sub
```

Here is my data, from A1 to C24 (I am sorry, but I don't know how to post data; I hope this okay):

```
202T1   0.391247362 2.834369777
202T2   0.691781786 2.666707207
202T3   0.872761164 2.330032099
202T4   1.057514239 2.251776009
203T1   1.088302698 2.125477081
203T2   1.143134672 2.058478339
203T3   1.230010336 1.898660815
203T4   1.352647337 1.825980361
204T1   1.407629265 1.625067932
204T2   1.604651381 1.429848476
204T3   1.660545527 1.429355775
204T4   1.625135728 1.358984468
205T1   1.591302544 1.433342365
205T2   1.421485471 1.627178459
205T3   1.308766495 1.742698395
205T4   1.285293375 1.767906794
206T1   1.286042017 1.90493934
206T2   1.370711841 1.878064404
206T3   1.527638431 1.841714946
206T4   1.699015299 1.766386414
207T1   2.241359446 1.547066284
207T2   2.620694291 1.339110863
207T3   3.219738778 1.015269389
207T4   3.894292001 0.683653342
```

I'm so sorry--I didn't realize that I would need to provide the code! I actually originally did everything through the GUI, so I didn't have any code, but here it is now!

Comment: try to give a detailed information about your question. Add your code , what issue your facing? , where your blocking? , what you tried so far? like the way you have to ask your question. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though concur    completely with @Agilanbu. However if it is regarding color of marker may try something in this direction. `Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(X).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(192, 80, 77)`. (or similar with datalabels).Try to wrap it with in a for loop with step of 6.   If it is regarding Axis TickLabels then it is real tricky. May refer the [link](http://www.andypope.info/charts/hiliteaxislabels.htm) or [link2](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/382212-multiple-color-labels-x-axis.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me even though I did not follow the rules! I originally just made my graphs through the GUI, so I didn't actually have any code, but I've added some now that would replicate the graph I uploaded. I haven't tried your solution yet, but I'm very excited to. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I managed to solve it with Ahmed AU's first link, as well as this one: https://peltiertech.com/individual-format-category-axis-labels/

Comment: Hello Joe Donaghue Happy to be able to provide even smallest help. Moreover I my view your 1st question in SO is a real challenger.